# How to expand the elements of a numpy matrix into sub matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]]
```

What is the easiest way to expand the elements into submatrices?
An intermediary result could look like this:

```
x = np.array([[[[1, 1],[1, 1]], [[2, 2],[2, 2]]],
              [[[3, 3],[3, 3]], [[4, 4],[4, 4]]]]
```

And the desired result:

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
              [1, 1, 2, 2],
              [3, 3, 4, 4],
              [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `repeat`s over the desired axes:

```
In [34]: np.repeat(np.repeat(x, 2, 1), 2, 0)
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Or as a faster approach (more suitable for larger arrays and repeat numbers) you can use `as_strided`:

```
In [43]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [44]: x, y = arr.shape

In [45]: xs, ys = arr.strides

In [46]: result = as_strided(arr, (x, 2, y, 2), (xs, 0, ys, 0))

In [47]: result.reshape(x*2, y*2)
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.repeat` for the task. It has an `axis` argument.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

>>> np.repeat(a, 2)
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])

>>> np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])

>>> np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=1), 2, axis=0)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```